# Is it possible to overload += operator in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

Is it possible to overload += operator in Swift to accept for example `CGFloat` arguments? If so, how?

My approach (below) does not work.

```
infix operator += { associativity left precedence 140 }
public func +=(inout left: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) {
    left = left + right
}
```

---

### (Edit) Important:

The coding approch above actually works. Please [see my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747083/311865) for explanation why I thought it did not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am sorry, my bad. The operator += does not need to be overloaded for `CGFloat` arguments as such overload is included in Swift. I was trying to do something like

```
let a: CGFloat = 1.5
a += CGFloat(2.1)
```

This failed because I cannot asign to `let` and the error displayed by XCode confused me.

And of course, approach like in my original question (below) works for overloading operators.

```
infix operator += { associativity left precedence 140 }
public func +=(inout left: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) {
    left = left + right
}
```

Please feel free to vote to close this question.

Answer (score 6):

The `+=` operator for `CGFloat` is already available, so you just have to use it - the only thing you can do is override the existing operator if you want it to behave in a different way, but that's of course discouraged.

Moreover, the `+=` operator itself already exists, so there is no need to declare it again with this line:

```
infix operator += { associativity left precedence 140 }
```

You should declare a new operator only if it's a brand new one, such as:

```
infix operator <^^> { associativity left precedence 140 }
```

However, if you want to overload the `+=` operator for other type(s) for which it is not defined, this is the correct way:

```
func += (inout lhs: MyType, rhs: MyType) {
    lhs = // Your implementation here
}
```

Comment: Please see my own answer

Comment: Yeah just read that. Funny thing is, I did the same error as you while testing my code... fortunately I already knew the operator exists :)

Comment: Cool coincidence :) Thank you for your answer anyway

Comment: This helped, I forgot to put `inout`. However, in newer swift versions, it would be:

`static func += (lhs: inout MyType, rhs: MyType)`